# How do I get Nightwatch to show Chai assertions in the reporter?

Tags: chai, nightwatch.js

I'm using [Nightwatch JS v0.9.16](https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch) to run selenium / [chai](http://chaijs.com/guide/styles/#assert) tests on my localhost. All the assertions work for nightwatch, but I can't get the chai assertion to show in the reporter.

This issue has been discussed here: https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/issues/601 however it's been closed but there was no resolution... can anyone get this to work yet?

Here's my test:

```js
var assert = require('chai').assert;

module.exports = {
  'pressing the "Servers" tab should change the URL to #servers' : function (client) {
    const pages = client.page,
          home_page = pages.home(),
          servers_page = pages.servers();

    home_page.navigate();
    servers_page.expect.element('body').to.be.present.before(1000);
    client.pause(1000);
    servers_page.click('@nav');
    servers_page.expect.element('@servers_div').to.be.present.before(1000);
    client.url(function(response){
        var currentUrl = response.value.replace(client.launch_url,"");
        console.log("url is ",response.value);

        //***CHAI ASSERTION doesn't get shown on reporter:***
        assert(currentUrl.indexOf('#servers')!=-1);

        client.end();
    });

  }
};
```

Screenshot of when this test passes shows all the assertions except the chai one:

[image: chai test passed]

And when it fails it shows `AssertionError: Unspecified AssertionError`:

[image: chai test failure]

Here's my test settings (nightwatch.json)

```
{
  "src_folders" : ["tests"],
  "output_folder" : "reports",
  "custom_commands_path" : "",
  "custom_assertions_path" : "",
  "page_objects_path" : "./config/pages/",
  "globals_path" : "./config/globals.js",

  "selenium" : {
    "start_process" : false,
    "server_path" : "./libs/selenium-server-standalone-2-53-1.jar",
    "log_path" : "./logs/",
    "port" : 4444
  },

  "test_settings" : {
    "default" : {
      "launch_url" : "http://localhost:8081",
      "selenium_port"  : 9515,
      "selenium_host"  : "localhost",
      "default_path_prefix" : "",
      "screenshots" : {
        "enabled" : true,
        "path" : "./screens/",
        "on_failure": true
      },
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "chromeOptions" : {
          "args" : ["--no-sandbox"]
        },
        "acceptSslCerts": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Versions:

```
"selenium-webdriver": "^3.0.1",
"nightwatch": "^0.9.8",
"chromedriver": "^2.25.2",
"chai": "latest"
```

Comment: Really hopin' someone has a solution for this, as well.

Answer (score 1):

According to the doc, `assert()` takes a message as 2nd arg (http://www.chaijs.com/api/assert/), did you try it out? If so, was the message displayed?

Alternatively, have you tried with simpler tests (one failing, one not) for example: `assert.isOk(false)` & `assert.isOk(true)`?

Last, did you try running your chai assertion outside of `client.url()` 's callback?

I am not familiar with Nightwatch, but that's what I would have tried.

Comment: Hey Nicolas! Thanks, I'll give this a try!